# How to alter a datatype on a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, bash, syntax

So this is the method i've been using: "ALTER TABLE galaxy ALTER COLUMN body_type TYPE UNIQUE;

And I get an error, and a pointer appears under the U in UNIQUE. I would have posted a picture if I could have. What is the correct method to change the data type?

Comment: @PM 77-1 Yes, it did. Thanks for the quick answer. Guess I should have searched a little further

Comment: you need two comands https://dbfiddle.uk/7RjIZg2n